# stroke применить pattern

Tags: svg

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' style='border: 1px solid black'>
   <pattern id="newpattern"
             x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
               
            <g fill="#85D2FF"  fill-opacity="0.7">
             <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" />
             <rect x="10" y="10" width="10" height="10" />
            </g>
      </pattern>
  <circle stroke-width='url(#newpattern)' stroke='blue' fill='green'  r="100" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
</svg>
```

Comment: pattern это типа background + background-repeat одновременно - что Вы добиваетесь ?

Comment: @ MaximLensky добавил ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stroke - в этом аттрибуте указывают заливку

stroke-width - здесь указывают толщину

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' style='border: 1px solid black'>
   <pattern id="newpattern"
             x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
               
            <g fill="#85D2FF"  fill-opacity="0.7">
             <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" />
             <rect x="10" y="10" width="10" height="10" />
            </g>
      </pattern>
  <circle stroke='url(#newpattern)' stroke-width='30' fill='green'  r="100" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Хотел добавить  в рамку pattern

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' style='border: 1px solid black'>
   <pattern id="newpattern"
             x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
            <g fill="#85D2FF"  fill-opacity="0.7">
             <polygon points="20,30 40,10 60,30" fill='red'/>
            </g>
      </pattern>
  <circle stroke-width='20' stroke='url(#newpattern)' fill='green'  r="100" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
</svg>
```